# How to line up fixed and absolute positioned elements

Tags: css

I am using a page transition that involves a fixed line scrolling down and lining up with an absolutely positioned line on the next page break.

I understand that fixed and absolute positioned elements don't render position in the same way, but I am confused as to why this is the case, and how to solve it.

```
/* These elements need to line up horizontally, but do not */

div.line-one {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20vw;
}

div.line-two {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20vw;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `fixed` elements are positioned relative to the entire document ( window/screen ) . `absolute` elements are positioned relative to the parent that has `relative` position. If you don't post your html structure and create a working example of your problem...we can't help you

Comment: My apologies, the absolute positioned element is in a container with 100% width and no margins/padding. I was trying for brevity :)

Comment: add a full snippet that reproduces your issue and explain well what do you need to achieve

Answer (score 1):

They are both taken out of the normal document flow and positioned where they should be, at the same place. Because of their defined *positions* they do not interfere with one another.

The only "relation" between the two is the stacking order in the DOM, therefore the *absolutely positioned div* is placed on top of the *fixed one*, because it comes after it in the HTML.

```css
.line-one {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20vw;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1; /* just so that you can see both; remove it and you'll see it's hidden under the "absolute" */
}

.line-two {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20vw;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-one">fixed</div>
<div class="line-two">absolute</div>
```

So in order to place them next to each other you need to "push" one of them by the *width* of the other, preferably using the *CSS* `calc()` *function*:

```css
.line-one {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20vw;
  background: red;
}

.line-two {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(20vw + 32px);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-one">fixed</div>
<div class="line-two">absolute</div>
```